# ASP.Net: Enable timeout in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, timeout, executiontimeout

In ASP.Net the debug mode extends timeout to 30,000,000 seconds despite `executionTimeout`. But what if I want to debug the "timeout cases"? How to enable it?

Thanks.